# Random Generator Displaying Strings

Tags: java, android

There are no error in my code but it won't show the random string that I want it to show. I would like for the fragment to have a different string everytime it loads.  I changed my question.java.

question.java

```
       import android.content.Context;
       import android.content.res.Resources;
       import android.net.Uri;
       import android.util.Log;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
       import android.view.LayoutInflater;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.view.ViewGroup;
       import android.widget.TextView;




        import java.util.Random;


        public class question extends Fragment {




      private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

       private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
       //public randomQuestion t1 = new randomQuestion();

      private String[] myQuestions;
       private static final Random random = new Random();
        private TextView question;




public question() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    TextView question = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.question);
    EditText answere = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.enterTxt);

    Resources res = getResources();
    myQuestions = res.getStringArray(R.array.myQuestions);
    String q = myQuestions[new Random().nextInt(myQuestions.length)];
    question.setText(q);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
   // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
    question = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.question);
    question.setText(myQuestions[random.nextInt(myQuestions.length)]);
    return rootView;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
     }
  }
```

array.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <string-array name="myQuestions">
       <item> String 1</item>
       <item>String 2</item>
       <item>String 3</item>
       <item> String 4</item>
       <item> String 5</item>
     </string-array>
   </resources>
```

This turns up in the logcat when I open the fragment it turns up red.

06-13 10:50:53.653 13733-13784/com.theneworange.lock E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa971570

Strings.xml

```
     <resources>
    <string name="app_name">"App "</string>
    <string name="turn_on">Turn On</string>
    <string name="turn_off">Turn Off</string>
    <string name="to_turn_on_press_turn_on_button">To turn on press Turn On        button</string>
    <string name="to_turn_off_press_turn_off_button">To turn off press Turn     Off button</string>

<string-array name="myQuestions">
    <item> String 1</item>
    <item>String 2</item>
    <item>String 3</item>
    <item> String 4</item>
    <item> String 5</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: The code is incomplete; it's hard for us to see where you've declared your variables and that kind of thing. Make sure we're able to see all of the constructs involved.

Comment: Sorry forgot to put the XML file in.

Comment: I think it's `question.java` that needs fixing! ;p

Comment: You must update the question you posted with the required information, don't post it in the comments. This is harder to read and does not fix the original question, which will deter other users on the site from helping you.

Comment: No, just the aspects which are part of the problem. :-)

Comment: Please grab the full logcat, not just one line (if there is truly an error)

Answer (score 1):

Need to move this line into onCreateView because the is no View to get at the class level.

```
TextView question = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.question);
```

So, fix the fields. Something like so

```
private String[] myQuestions;
private static final Random random = new Random();
private TextView question;
```

Then,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
    question = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.question);
    question.setText(myQuestions[random.nextInt(myQuestions.length)];
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that @cricket_007 and I'm getting the same error. Its a blank screen with no words., I will post my code above.

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. According to here, at least, you should put your array into strings.xml https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: I created a different resource file named array.xml should that be the cause.

Comment: It should be `res/values/arrays.xml` (plural) but try putting it in `strings.xml` first

Comment: The same thing happened.  Nothing shows up.I will post my strings above

Comment: Are you even loading the Fragment into the Activity?

Comment: Yes I added a fragment to my main activity.